# Keyboard doesn't work in certain applications when using an external monitor

Tags: 11.10, display, input

When connect to external monitor and extend display to ext minitor, keyborad input does not work for certain application(Java UI, eg username, password input dialog).

In single monitor mode, never has this type of problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Did a lot of attempts, when I set resolution for external monitor at a lower value, it sometimes works.

But a random problem, probability on my machine is > 50%.